# what is the limit to set the size of stack using setstacksize function in pthread?

Tags: c, unix

when I set the stack size using the setstack size like this.

```
    ret=pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr,1000);
    printf("%d\n",ret);
    pthread_attr_getstacksize(&attr,&size);
```

The setstacksize is returning non-zero values, which indicates that the size has not been set.
And the getstacksize is printing the garbage value.
but if I give the size greater than 16384 the stack is set and return 0.
and the getstacksize returns 16384.

can someone tell me why the setstacksize if taking the size greater than 16384, Is there any limit for setting the stack size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html), "possible errors":

> `EINVAL`: The stack size is less than `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` (16384) bytes.
>
> On some systems, pthread_attr_setstacksize() can fail with the error `EINVAL` if stacksize is not a multiple of the system page size.